# Solving system of constrained linear and non-linear equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, finite-element, nonlinear-equations, constrained-optimization

Solving system of constrained linear and non-linear equations in MATLAB

I'm solving a FEM problem in MATLAB with use of the direct stiffness method. The problem is now formulated as a system of nn linear equations:

$KU=F$ or $CF=U$ with $C = K^{-1}$.

the problem is formulated in 3-Dd and has over 200 nodes. The model is used as a deformation estimator, the force is always the input and the deformation output. So there are a lot of linear equations. Now this problem needs to be extended, 2 types of constraints need to be implemented. Some of the nodes have to be constrained so that they only can move in a circular motion around a given point. And some of the nodes have to be bound with a maximum amount of deformation.

in total there will hundreds of equations of the form equations of the form:

$a_1 X(1) + a_2 X(2) + \cdots - F(1) = 0$

about 10 equality constraints of a nonlinear form like (could also be a sinusoid):

$X(1)^2 + X(2)^2 = L$

and 10 inequality constraints of the form:

$X(1) < 30\pi/180$

What is the best method to solve a nonlinear system of equations with constraints of this type simultaneously? Is it possible to use fsolve? Or fmincon? I've been looking into solvers but I can't find a solid conclusion on what solver can handle all these equation types at once and what would be most efficient in terms of computation time.